# Node.js sever on ubuntu not receiving requests

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server, netstat

When I place the IP Adress of the server and the port on the browser, there is no response and it does not get to the server. Here are some stats from the server; I am running the server on port 5403

```
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5403                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5403 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Another command

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25324           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5403                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

You only listen to ipv6, this often pose a problem. Try to disable IPv6 and run on IPv4 address in stead.

Comment: This still does not fix it